# Insurance coverage when staying in Switzerland during Corona pandemic as Swiss national with residency in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance, switzerland, ehic

I am a Swiss citizen living and working in London. Mid March I made a trip to Switzerland and decided to stay here for the time of the Corona pandemic. During that time I will continue working remotely for an office in London. I have an EHIC and am insured under NHS - my travel insurance plan I purchased only covers travels for up to 2 weeks.
Is there a need for any additional insurance coverage or am I sufficiently covered? Additionally - do I have to purchase a Swiss insurance at one point if I am going to stay in Switzerland for several months (even if working/being a resident in London)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A general answer to this question will not be possible, since there are factors that are dependent on the individual countries (Switzerland and United Kingdom).

In general the [EHIC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card) is intended for basic coverage during  *visits* to other participanting countries.

So the following questions must be clarified:

- for how long is the NHS willing to pay bills incurred outside the UK
- does Switzerland (and their health services) consider you a resident

Independent of the present circumstances, you are residing **outside** the United Kingdom in Switzerland after a period of 3 months.

For this, you should make sure you have a coverage (as a resident, not as a traveler) that will deal with all heath costs within Switzerland during your residence there.

---

**Note**:

> **[Participating member states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card)**
>   ... as well as the UK while it is in the so called transition period after it withdrew from the EU on 31 January 2020.

---

**Sources**:

- [European Health Insurance Card - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card)